A ConcurrentTaskQueue that preserves SynchronizationContext and allows original caller to await
This is a task queue in a background service that preserves the original callers SynchronizationContext.
It returns a Task<Task> or Task<Task<T>> to the original caller which completes once the task is queued and reaches the finished state.
It also is able to run multiple tasks concurrently by setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism before the dequeue loop starts.
Please roast me!
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ConcurrentTaskQueue : BackgroundService
{
    Channel<Func<Task>> _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Func<Task>>();

    private bool _started = false;

    private int _maxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    public int MaxDegreeOfParallelism
    {
        get => _maxDegreeOfParallelism;
        set
        {
            if (_started)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot set MaxDegreeOfParallelism after queue has already been started");
            }

            _maxDegreeOfParallelism = value;
        }
    }

    private SemaphoreSlim? _semaphore;

    public Task<Task> EnqueueTask(Func<Task> task)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Task> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Task>();

        SynchronizationContext? currentCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        Func<Task> actual = async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                SynchronizationContext? ctxToRestore = SynchronizationContext.Current;

                if (currentCtx is not null)
                {
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(currentCtx);
                }

                Task t;

                try
                {
                    t = task();
                }
                finally
                {
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(ctxToRestore);
                }

                await t.ConfigureAwait(false);
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(t);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore!.Release();
            }
        };

        _channel.Writer.TryWrite(actual);

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public Task<Task<T>> EnqueueTask<T>(Func<Task<T>> task)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Task<T>> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Task<T>>();

        SynchronizationContext? currentCtx = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        Func<Task> actual = async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                SynchronizationContext? ctxToRestore = SynchronizationContext.Current;

                if (currentCtx is not null)
                {
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(currentCtx);
                }

                Task<T> t;

                try
                {
                    t = task();
                }
                finally
                {
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(ctxToRestore);
                }

                await t.ConfigureAwait(false);
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(t);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException e)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetCanceled(e.CancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore!.Release();
            }
        };

        _channel.Writer.TryWrite(actual);

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _started = true;
        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(MaxDegreeOfParallelism, MaxDegreeOfParallelism);
        await foreach (var func in _channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync(stoppingToken);

            _ = func(); // don't await here, any exception should be caught by the original caller
        }
    }
}



@pacmaninbw This is code from a project that I'm working on.

Okay, I'm leaving your comment for others to read. I was not the one to down vote the question so I can't do anything about that.

Welcome to Codereview. Why do you care about the SynchronizationContext? Which .NET version are we talking about?
